# View the workflow in VS 2010

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to view the functions being called one after the other when I click on some web page. Obviously I have the code running on my local machine.
I have used Visual Studio 2010 for the development.
Is there a tool to do that where I can see which function is calling the other in VS 2010 apart from using breakpoints?

Comment: Can you set breakpoints, or is the code running on another machine?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but it's worth a look.

If you right click on a method name in the code window and select "**View Call Hierarchy**" (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+T) it will display the Call Hierarchy window (Ctrl+W, K) with the selected method as the root. This will allow you to browse the calls to and calls from the selected method.

It is a tree view, and by expanding the required nodes you can drill as far down the call hierarchy as you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

[Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me) can do it. To monitor ASP.NET you will need to use *Customized Run* as described in *Quick Start*.